# WPML Woocommerce Support

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml, qtranslate

My website is multilingual(En,fr,rs) having woocommerce created by using the qTranslate plugin. But the problem is that, I am unable to translate woocommerce message (cart, checkout, email contents) but fortunately achieved with jQuery except email notification and thank you order page.

At the last WPML paid plugin purchased but how to use it only for woocommerce(cart, checkout, email contents etc) pages and I don't want WPML functionality over all the site.

Is there any setting to disable WPML for the site where enable only for woocommerce section only, because I have already achieved my task as I want with qTranslate?

One more thing don't suggest "qTranslate to WPML importer" plugin which is useless for my site. Your help will be very appreciable.

Comment: You'd have better luck asking this on WPML support forums than here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need WPML String Translation and Woo Multilingual Plugin by WPML to translate those items.

On other hand, if your website is made in 1 language, you can use PO files to translate such staff. Don;t forget about special software for proper editing.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Oliver to reply, Now I have done my task myself but want to know that is there possibility or any setting to modify(translate) the woocommerce message only for Ex: "Your order is processing"

Comment: Is this an exact string? Couldnt locate one

Answer (score 0):

@oliver is right but WPML is one of the Worst multilingual plugin for WordPress as it down the site and by which it hammers the SEO and speed of site.

I have used WPML on 4 sites and its a average rating.